# How to move logo of app at center in Master detail page xamarin.forms?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

Hi I am working on xamarin.forms. I am using master detail page. In actin bar I have Menu items icon and app logo. I want to place the app logo at center and menu items on left side. But while using Master detail page both menu item button and app icon both are at left side.

I tried to use xml file to make app icon at center but in that case menu item button is invisible.

Please can any one tell me how I can move the app icon at center in master detail page? and at left side menu item should be displayed.
[image]

I need to shift the HubSystem Logo horiznotally center. I am using master detail page. I also need to show menu items, so I am using menu button before Hubsystem logo. Please tell me how I can move HubSystem logo at center.

Regards,
Anand Dubey

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing your issue. Can you post a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: @KeithRome, I have added the image please look it and please update How I can move HubSystem logo at center.

Comment: Can you share your xaml being used as well? Just enough to show how the layout of the master and detail pages are being done.